# Absence of texture on 3D model in AR application made with Unity 3D and Region Capture

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on a little AR coloring book application using Unity and Vuforia. I did something similar a few years back, but now, with the new updates, they changed a lot of things (I'm using Unity 2017.3, Vuforia 7 and Texture Region Capture 2.0.6 available here https://github.com/maximrouf/RegionCapture).

When the Image Target is shown, a 3D model of that image appears and you should be able to color it. The problem is that on the 3D model I can see all the things captured by the camera, not only the texture, as shown in the image below. [image: play mode]

Now, I don't know the reason for this, I tried looking at other tutorials, but even the scripts for this version of Region Capture differ. Below are some pictures containing the way I attached the cameras and the game object to the scripts.[image: Image Target][image: Region Capture][image: Region Camera].

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @patri

Comment: Unfortunately not yet...

Comment: @sumit mehra I ended up not using this at all. In my final solution I created for each image a 3D object and for each object, taking into consideration the complexity and the details I wanted, I added colliders. It becomes a lot easier changing the colors when they get triggered.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem today so I post here the solution hoping that this will help people who encounter the same problem.

To solve it, I had to link the Region Capture to my Image Target and resize it to match the Image Target's size:

[image: avoid Region Capture from taking entire camera]